# Search Active Directory using LDAP

Tags: asp.net, ldap

I am searching department name in active directory using LDAP but it is throwing exception when it have to display and the exception is

> invalidcastexception was unhandled

Code:

```
If dSearchResult.Properties.Contains("department") 
Then
   If dSearchResult.Properties("department")(0).ToString
```

Throwing exception at `ToString`.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You're using [cast syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x53d8wxa.aspx) - what you want is the index and value of that property :

```
Dim department As String
department = dSearchResult.Properties["department"][0].ToString
```